# How to calculate grand total in mysql without group by clause in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

i want to get grand `total` of a column without using `group by clause` as i don't want to `concat` any string.

**i looking for this kind desired result:**

```
|  customer id | project name | Product Name | Quantity | price  | total    |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------+----------+
|     9        |  xyz         |   ppn        |   2      |   2    |   4      |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------+----------+
|    11        |    pqr       |    xxx       |    2     |   2    |    4     |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------+--------+----------+
|              |              |              |          |        |     8    |<=== Grand total  
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

here is SQL Fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/30fdd5/2

Comment: I don't see what `group by` and `concat()` have to do with each other.

Comment: How do you want to display different kinds of product all bought by customer 11 with different prices on a grouping construct if if not by concating the different names, amounts and prices  with this table still making any sense afterwards?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT customer_id, project_name, product_name, quantity,
       price, quantity * price as total 
FROM project_expenses_data
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, sum(quantity * price)
FROM project_expenses_data;
```

To be 100% clear that the total is the last row in the result set, add the clause `ORDER BY (customer_id IS NULL) ASC`.